# Entity Framework code first server database does not get updated

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, azure

I am using Entity Framework code first migration in MVC to create a database on Azure SQL server. While creating a new web app, I chose "MVC" from "ASP.NET 4.5.2 Templates" with "Authentication = Individual User Accounts" and "Host in the cloud " checked.

My IdentityModels.cs looks like this -

```
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }



        // I added this method to create a mapping using fluent APIs to fix some error I was getting while updating migration.
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });

           // modelBuilder.Entity<CloudUnitLib.UnitOfMeasure>().HasKey(k => k.UnitId);
        }
   }
```

I added tables "MyTable-1", "MyTable-2", "MyTable-3" & "MyTable-4" to the database. Ran the application LOCALLY which created following tables in the local database -
dbo._MigrationHistory, dbo.ApplicationUsers, dbo.IdentityRoles, dbo.IdentityUserClaims, dbo.IdentityUserLogins, dbo.IdentityUserRoles and finally tables added by me which are "MyTable-1", "MyTable-2", "MyTable-3" & "MyTable-4".

The problem occurred when I published the web app on the cloud. It created following tables in the Azure database -
dbo._MigrationHistory, dbo.AspNetRoles, dbo.AspNetUserClaims, dbo.AspNetUserLogins, dbo.AspNetUserRoles, dbo.AspNetUsers.

- **Question 1:** Why the table names in local database and server database not matching?
- **Question 2:** Where do these AspNetXXX tables getting generated from? Because there is no code in my application which would generate
  tables with these names.
- **Question 3:** When I try to update the database using following series of commands, it tries to drop tables with names
  "IdentityXXXX", which are obviously not present in the server
  database, and throws an error! How to fix this?

  1. Update-database  –TargetMigration $InitialDatabase
  2. Add-migration Initial –Force
  3. Update-database
- **Question 4:** None of the tables added by me which are "MyTable-X" getting added in the server database. Why?

Because all the tables are present in the local database, the application runs perfectly fine when I run it locally. But it doesn't run on the server.

I would appreciate any help. I am really confused.

Thank you

Comment: that's a strange issue.. almost sounds like your code is referencing 2 different versions of aspnet.identity,